# Textbook clarification: $\log = \ln$

Tags: logarithms

Textbook reads:

> All logarithms are natural logarithms: $\log = \ln$.

Does this mean $n\log(n) = n\ln(n)$?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus That phrase is a terrible phrase to teach computer scientists. In --most-- cases, our "log" is base 2, not e or 10. For instance, the "log" in the traditional merge sort's `n log n` is base 2. With a phrase like that, I'd start to question everything in that book (even more so than the standard academic question everything stance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the textbook is making clear that you should read $\log n$ to mean $\ln n$, then yes, barring any subscript for a base other than $e$, $n \log(n) = n\ln(n)$.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of this answer, and you should - they've made it clear they're using the two interchangeably. It should be noted, however, that in the context of OP (using this for computational complexity) such a phrase is a dangerous one and probably should be avoided. I hope they supplied a significant amount of background about how complexity analysis works, and a justification of how they arrived at such a seemingly terrible decision.

Comment: @corsiKa Notice that often there is a hidden constant in factor (like in $O(log(n))$), so it's harmless to use natural log. Also, logarithm in base $2$ is often denoted $lg$ instead of $log$ or $ln$.

Comment: That constant is probably the rationale for them using `ln` everywhere. It's just a bit misleading to say it's always the natural log, when log2 and log10 are much, much more common in a typical algorithms course.

Answer (score 5):

If $\log = \ln$, then yes, indeed, $n\log n = n\ln n$.

Note, however, that this is utterly unimportant if you are looking at it from the case of the big $O$ notation, which is highly likely, since

$$n\log n \in O(n\ln n)$$
and $$n\ln n \in O(n\log n)$$
or, in other words, $$O(n\log n)=O(n\ln n)$$

Comment: Completely agree - I could see a function similar to `atoi` being based on the base of the number being parsed, but thanks to the math behind logarithms they're all in the same base. It's not like you'd have `O(n log-k n)` - it would just be `O(n lg n)` no matter if it was base 2, e, 10, or 36.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the base of a logarithm must be specified as $\log_a$. A very common convention is $\ln \equiv \log_e$.

However, $\log$ without subscript can mean a few different things based on the context (and therefore must be always explicitly stated).

$\log \equiv \log_{10}$, **is very common in many mathematical books and publications**.

$\log \equiv \log_2$, **in computer science**.

$\log \equiv \ln$, **in most physics and applied mathematical contexts**.

Your textbook is in the latter category. It can still use other bases for logarithms, but unspecified means base $e$.

Comment: Mathematical books and publications universally use $\log \equiv \ln$ (at least, past the middle- or high-school level, where it can be assumed that the reader is familiar with $e$); there's no mathematical reason to use $10$ as a base for the logarithm instead of $e$, which conveniently has $(\log x)' = 1/x$. Some engineering texts, or more generally texts that involve lots of numeric computation, might use $\log\equiv \log_{10}$.

Comment: Some domains of mathematics may make the implicit assumption of $\log \equiv \ln$ but given the dominates of the decimal number system, $\log_{10}$ often is convenient, and will use $\log \equiv \log_{10}$. In my experience any _textbook_ in mathematics or computer science will explicitly mention which based is the default assumption for $\log$ when not specified.

Comment: @mctylr $\log_{10}$ may be convenient in some contexts, even in some mathematical contexts, but the overwhelming majority of mathematics uses $\log$ to denote the natural logarithm. Mostly without even mentioning it, since it is so natural.

Comment: @anomaly Actually I have very rarely come across the $\log \equiv \ln$ case because $\ln$ is already a shorter way to write it. In textbooks I've used so far $\log$ goes to the next most useful base which is either $10$ or $2$ depending on the context. Maybe usage varies by region and time period.

Comment: Any specific textbooks in mind? It's not that I don't believe you; I've just literally never seen $\log\equiv \log_{10}$ since high school (see also: $\div$). I've seen a few calculus tests use $\ln$ consistently, but $\log$ is vastly more common in my experience. There's just no reason to ever use $\log_{10}$ unless you're going through a pile of numerical computation with large numbers, which is not something that comes up in math.

Comment: @anomaly After some more research, it seems that $\log \equiv \log_{10}$ might mostly be an engineering thing (I'm an electrical engineer) and I assumed it was more common than it actually is because our classes always worked with the assumption that $\log \equiv \log_{10}$ and $\ln \equiv \log_e$.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that unless some other base is specified, the base of the logarithm is assumed to be $e$.  That is, if you see $\log x$, the author means $\log_e x$, which can also be written $\ln x$.

The rule $\log_b x^n = n\log_b x$ holds for any base $b > 0$, with $b \neq 1$.  In particular, it holds for $b = e$, so the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. These notations are same. For example $\log x=\ln x$.